# What is wrong with my c code?

Tags: c

I am getting segmentation fault for the code below. To compile I typed `gcc -std=c99 -g alphacode.c`. This is a problem I am solving from [here](http://www.spoj.pl/problems/ACODE/), and I am not sure what the problem is.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int catchar(char a, char b) {

  char a1[2];
  a1[1] = a;
  a1[0] = b;

  return atoi(a1);
}

int processNumber(char *num) {
 int size = strlen(num);
 int p[size];

 if (num[size-1] != 0)
   p[size-1] = 1;
 else
   p[size-1] = 0;

 int i;
 for (i = size-2; i>=0; i--)
    {

      if (catchar(num[i], num[i-1]) > 26 ||
      catchar(num[i] , num[i-1]) <1 || num[i] == 0) 
    p[i] = p[i-1];    
      else
    p[i] = p[i-1] + p[i-2];

    }

 return p[0];

}


int main() {

    int bytes_read;
    int nbytes = 5000;
    char *number;
    bytes_read = getline (&number, &nbytes, stdin);
    while (bytes_read != -1) {

      int out = processNumber(number);
      printf("%d\n", out);
      bytes_read = getline (&number, &nbytes, stdin);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Run [gdb](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) on your program, it will tell you exactly where the segmentation fault occurs.

Comment: @Sjoerd: gdb complains: _IO_getdelim (lineptr=0x7fffffffe8e8, n=0x7fffffffe8f8, delimiter=10, fp=0x7ffff7dd66a0) at iogetdelim.c:47
47 iogetdelim.c: No such file or directory.
 in iogetdelim.c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int catchar(char a, char b) {

  char a1[2];
  a1[1] = a;
  a1[0] = b;

  return atoi(a1);
}
```

`atoi()` expects a string, and a string must have a `'\0'` terminator, without it - `atoi()` will just keep looking until it find `'\0'`, and you might get garbage or segfault - if you are out of your allocated memory.

You should declare your array of size 3, and put `'\0'` at index 2.

Comment: Do you know why gdb complains: _IO_getdelim (lineptr=0x7fffffffe8e8, n=0x7fffffffe8f8, delimiter=10, fp=0x7ffff7dd66a0) at iogetdelim.c:47
47 iogetdelim.c: No such file or directory.
 in iogetdelim.c

Comment: The getline function (line 47) expects a file to read, but in the way you give it the parameter "number" your array should be declared char number[20], for instance, not "char* number";

Comment: @NicolasC: I am still getting the same error from GDB. Maybe there's something wrong with my compiler/debugger?

Answer (score 0):

String needs to be null(0) terminated, thus you need array of 3 ( [a][b][\0]).

```
int catchar(char a, char b) 
{
  char concat[3] = { a,b,NULL};

  return atoi(concat);
}
```

Comment: Declaring an array of 2 elements and pushing three elements into it causing an immediate stack overflow?

Comment: Yes my bad, fixed (it'd cause error during compilation actually).